# Android clip piece of image from bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an Image

[image]

and i want to clip a some piece of image using a [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html)

[image]

How i can do that?

I stucked after filling my path.

```
Path path = new Path();

if (pointsCount > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
        path.moveTo(pathPoint.getY1(), pathPoint.getY2());
        path.lineTo(point.getX(), point.getY());
    }
    path.close();
 } else {
    path.addRect(pathPoint.getX1(), pathPoint.getY1(), pathPoint.getX2(), pathPoint.getY2(), Path.Direction.CW);
    finalObject.setPath(path);
 }
```

I googled about how clip a some data from image but unfortunately i can't find any working examples.

Comment: did you read about "buildDrawingCache" ?

Comment: @LenaBru it's not a method which allow to clip data. It's just building bitmap of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll have to use the [`Canvas.clipPath(path)` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipPath(android.graphics.Path)), something like that:

```
private Bitmap clipBitmap(Bitmap original, Path path){
   Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
   Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
   c.clipPath(path);
   c.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
   return b;
}
```

ps.: I coded that super quick and without test, there're likely errors, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: Actually yes! clipPath is that what i need!